# Why is my code printing the same command line arguments twice?

Tags: c++, file

I passed three arguments to my program, which are all text files:
ARG 1: one
ARG 2: two
ARG 3: three

Why is ARG 1 being printed twice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc < 2)        //check if files exist 1st
{
    cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
}
else        //proceed if files exist
{
    for(int x = 1; x < argc; x++)       //while x < the argument count, read each argument
    {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open(argv[x]);
        if(!infile.is_open())     //check is file opens
        {
            cout << "Could not open file." << endl;
        }
        else        //if it opens, proceed
        {
            string s;
            while(infile.good())
            {
                infile >> s;        //declare string called s
                if(s[s.length()-1] == ',')      //if the end of the arg string has a ',' replace it with a null
                {
                    s[s.length()-1] = '\0';
                }
                cout << s;
                if(x != (argc -1))
                {
                    cout << ", ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

This code outputs:

> one, one, two, three

Comment: When you used the **debugger**, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables?

Comment: Rather than `while(infile.good())`, use `while (infile >> s)`.

Comment: If you just **pass a string** why open a **file?**

Comment: `argv[1]` isn't being printed at all in the code you provide.

Comment: this doesn't even reproduce for me. did you make sure the input files don't contain the string twice?

Comment: yeah I checked the text file and one only shows up once.                                    Edit: The problem is resolved. Thanks guys

Comment: put the contents of the file, so we can spot the bug faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your bug**

```
            cout << s; // here
            if(x != (argc -1))
            {
                cout << ", ";
            }
```

**how to fix**

```
            cout << s;
            s = ""; // fix
            if(x != (argc -1))
            {
                cout << ", ";
            }
```

You just putting the stream twice in the **s** string. That's it.

---

A short code for your purpose:

```
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for( std::size_t index = 1; index < argc; ++ index ){
        oss << std::ifstream( argv[ index ] ).rdbuf() ? assert(1==1) : assert(1==0);
    }
    std::cout << oss.str();
```

**Output**

```
one  
two  
three
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your suggestion and the output became: one, , two, three

Comment: EDIT: Nvm, I must've added an extra space in the text file

Comment: @DoABarrelRoll94. Please approve the post if it solved your problem. thanks. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)